# Can't open more than one connection to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm currently running a MySQL server on my localhost. When I try to open a second connection to the server, I always got this error:

```
mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102
```

When I checked for the current status of MySQL, I got these:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 151   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 1     |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I disconnect the current connection, I can immediately open another connection. Can someone tell me the reason of this error? My current MySQL server version is

```
Server version: 5.7.24 Homebrew
```